# LibSVM: Understanding the data format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, libsvm, file-format

I am currently experimenting with the LibSVM format as a standardized format for exchanging label/feature data sets between Python and Java in a Spark project. However, I am a bit confused by the multiple files starting with 'part-000*' that are created when saving the data (originally in Pandas DF, converted to RDD and LabeledPoints) using Spark's `MLUtil.util.saveAsLibSVMFile()`.

Why is the data split across multiple files and how can I save it to a single text file?
Or, alternatively, how can I read these multiple 'part-0000*' files?

AFAICS, the method `loadLibSVMFile()` in Spark's MLUtils.util requires a single file, which is strange; `saveAsLibSVMFile()` in the same util module will produce multiple files. Why this inconsistency?

Comment: Not sure who voted to close this question, but I think it is fine here, because it is related to the ML programming task at hand. The same question has already been rejected from the CrossValidated forum, so if you think it should be closed here, too, then at least suggest a better forum, please. Thank you.

Comment: It is possible to merge the "part" files, of course, like this:      

```with open(merged_libsvm_file, 'wb') as out_file:
        for f in filenames:
            with open(f, 'rb') as fd:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fd, out_file)``` 

But it still seems weird that load the file expected a different format from the one that has been saved by the same util module.